# Vlookup in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have created a form in excel which takes input from users and saves the same in Sheet2.  I have a combobox named Account from which users will select the name of account.  However each account will have a unique Id associated with it.  I dont want to expose this Id to the end users but at the same time I want the Id corresponding to the Account selected populated in sheet2.

I am trying to do a Vlookup to search for Id of the selected Account.

I have setup the Account values in Sheet3.

```
Example: 
Column A  ColumnB
Account1  Id12345
Account2  Id23456
Account3  Id34567
```

My code in excel macro looks something like below.

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim myValue as String

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
 .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.Account.Value
myValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A2"), Range("Sheet3!G1:G14"), 2, False)
```

I am not sure why it is not working.  Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Change `Range("Sheet3!G1:G14")` to `Sheet3.Range("G1:G14")`, or `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G1:G14")` or something along those lines.

Comment: I changed it to Sheet3.Range("G1:G14") it now throws an error stating    Runtime Error: 424; Object required.

Comment: That's because you're referring to just one column here when you're wanting to return the second column. `G1:G14` is just one column, but you're third argument is set to `2`. That will definitely throw an error. Either change your range to `G1:H14` or change your third argument to `1`.

Comment: I changed the code to myValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A2"), Sheeet3.Range("G1:H14"), 2, False), same error.

Comment: Thanks, @DougGlancy. Which line is highlighted when the error is thrown and what is the error now?

Comment: Error is the same Runtime Error: 424; Object required. it is the same kine that is highlighted "myValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A2"), Sheeet3.Range("G1:H14"), 2, False)"

Comment: also you might want to add an error handler on `Vlookup`. If it somehow fails to locate what your searching for (e.g. returns #N/A) it will throw error. Also no `End With`?

Comment: @L42. Good point. However, `1004` is pretty friendly at this point to handle, harhar. `424` is kind of a pain to locate at times.

Comment: He doesn't actually need the `With` part as his actions on `Sheet2` are minimal at best, unless he'll qualify his variables better. I believe this'll turn out as some exercise in best practices. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim RefRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Sh2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set Sh3 = .Sheets("Sheet3")
    End With

    RowCount = Sh2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Set RefRange = Sh3.Range("G1:H14") '--Change as necessary.

    Sh2.Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.Account.Value
    On Error GoTo myValueErrHandle
    myValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sh2.Range("A2").Value, RefRange, 2, False)
    '--More code, etc etc.

myValueErrHandle:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "No match using VLOOKUP."
    End If
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

As much as possible, qualify everything you can and use succinct but meaningful code. Don't use `Range("A2")` if you want what's inside it. Use `.Value` as this is the best practice. As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong. I also added an `Error 1004` handling for no matches. Lastly, note that I changed `myValue` to a `Variant`, just to cover bases.

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Thanks BK201, I tried your code.  It now throws a popup as "No Match using VLookup".  which suggests for some reason it is not able to find the corresponding Id for the account selected.

Comment: @user3175856: But is there supposed to be a match? Because if there isn't, then I think we've got the right code, haven't we? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this? : Sorry too long to put in comment:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.Account.Value
    myValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A2"), Sheeet3.Range("G1:H14"), 2, False)" 
End With
```

Just maybe, so try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Lookup()
Dim Emp As String
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
Dim Age As Single
Emp = "Jitu"
Set Lookup_Range = Range("A1:B8")
Age = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Emp, Lookup_Range, 2, False)

MsgBox "Age is : $ " & Age
End Sub
```

Table:
**Emp   Age**
bibhash 22
rahul   22
abhisek 23
jitu    21
sujit   24
tinku   25
rudra   26